# 404 Error in Authentication to Quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox

From this mornining i suddlenly gets this message in my app when i try to authenticate for to quickblox server it gives me  404 error. 
I need solution to this problem. can anyone give help to solve this issue. Please have look at following code:

```
QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(Consts.APP_ID,Consts.AUTH_KEY,Consts.AUTH_SECRET);
QBAuth.createSession(this);



01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): =========================================================
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): === REQUEST ==== 12f3a836-5d17-421b-aa0d-818d8c3fda5c ===
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): REQUEST
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): HEADERS
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     QB-SDK=Android 0.8.1
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): PARAMETERS
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     application_id=1758
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     auth_key=AUTH_KEY
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     nonce=84011634
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     timestamp=1390210957
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     signature=SIGNATURE

01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250): INLINE
01-20 15:12:37.698: D/QBASDK RestRequest(5250):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=1758&auth_key=SUTH_KEY&nonce=84011634&timestamp=1390210957&signature=SIGNATURE
01-20 15:12:37.788: V/!!!-deletion of 30 days older data--(5250): in dbhelper 
01-20 15:12:37.808: W/khrn_client(5250): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
01-20 15:12:37.808: W/khrn_client(5250): init_window window 0x4d6a60d8, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0
01-20 15:12:38.689: D/dalvikvm(5250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1185K, 11% free 16647K/18503K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 31ms
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): *********************************************************
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): *** RESPONSE *** 12f3a836-5d17-421b-aa0d-818d8c3fda5c ***
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): STATUS : 404 
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): HEADERS
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     Connection=keep-alive
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     Content-Length=169
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     Content-Type=text/html
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     Date=Mon, 20 Jan 2014 09:42:30 GMT
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     Server=nginx/1.0.15
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): BODY
01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250):     '<html>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): <body bgcolor="white">01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): <hr><center>nginx/1.0.15</center>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): </body>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): </html>01-20 15:12:38.960: D/QBASDK RestResponse(5250): '
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250): org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.RestResult.processResponse(RestResult.java:82)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at com.quickblox.module.auth.result.QBSessionResult.processResponse(QBSessionResult.java:31)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.RestResult.setResponse(RestResult.java:66)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at     com.quickblox.module.auth.result.QBSessionResult.setResponse(QBSessionResult.java:26)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:219)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:38)
01-20 15:12:38.960: W/System.err(5250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-20 15:12:38.970: W/System.err(5250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 15:12:38.970: D/QBASDK QBSessionResult(5250): Request has been completed with error: [Entity you are looking for was not found.]
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a scheduled server maintenance so some issues could occur. Everything works now.